# How to cancel thread in onPause() method in android

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
   super.onPause();
}

private void generateView() {
   for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
      ln_highlightprogress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      LinearLayout mview = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
      mview.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grayColor);
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(7, 40);
      layoutParams.setMargins(2, 0, 2, 0);
      mview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
      lnLinearlayout.addView(mview);
      Log.d("==================", "=================" + i);
      Log.v("==================", "=================" + i);
   }
   changeProgress();
}

private void changeProgress() {
   mChangeProgressThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
          // Update the progress status
          for (int i = 0; i < lnLinearlayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
             final int finalI = i;
             progressStatus = i;
             // Try to sleep the thread for 20 milliseconds
             try {
                  Thread.sleep(1000);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
             }
             // Update the progress bar
             handler.post(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                     if (highlightButtonWorkComplete && finalI == secondYellowColoredTextViewPosition) {
                     } else {
                       lnLinearlayout.getChildAt(finalI).setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                     }
                     if (finalI == (lnLinearlayout.getChildCount() - 1)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < lnLinearlayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                           if (highlightButtonWorkComplete && finalI == secondYellowColoredTextViewPosition) {
                              // leave this textview , as it is yellow ... go to next textview
                              secondYellowColoredTextViewPosition = 0;
                              highlightButtonWorkComplete = false;
                           } else {
                              lnLinearlayout.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.color.grayColor);
                           }
                        }
                        Log.d("Progress Status", "ProgressStatus" + progressStatus);
                        if (progressStatus % 79 == 0) {
                           lnLinearlayout.removeAllViews();
                           generateView();
                        }
                     }

                  }
             });
          }
       }
   });
   mChangeProgressThread.start();// Start the operation
}

private void changeHighlight() {
   secondYellowColoredTextViewPosition = progressStatus + endTime; //
   highlightButtonWorkComplete = true;
   lnLinearlayout.getChildAt(progressStatus - statartTime ).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(7, 100));
   lnLinearlayout.getChildAt(progressStatus - statartTime  ).setBackgroundResource(R.color.yellow);
   mHightlightThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final int size = endTime + (statartTime);
                for (int j = 0; j <= size - 1; j++) {
                    lastlopp = j;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            lnLinearlayout.getChildAt(progressStatus - statartTime).setBackgroundResource(R.color.yellow);
                            if (lastlopp == size - 1) {
                                lnLinearlayout.getChildAt(secondYellowColoredTextViewPosition).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, 100));
                                lnLinearlayout.getChildAt(secondYellowColoredTextViewPosition).setBackgroundResource(R.color.yellow);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                //got?yes .. may be calculation problem
            }
   });
   mHightlightThread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use boolean flag in thread. If boolean is true then execute your code else not. And in onPause method you can make false the boolean flag which you will use in thread code. Hope that helps

what you can do make a global boolean variable and on call of onPause set boolean true let's boolean is stopThread

```
stopThread = true
```

And in loop first check

```
if(stopThread) {
   break;
}
```

Comment: but suppose  thread is running and sudden i go back next actvtivity in that case thread is still running how i will stop in that case

Comment: I can see you are using loop, if that loop gets stop then your problem will be solved. You can use terminate statement like break

Comment: where i have to write terminate can please suggest

Comment: @Adevelopment now check I have added some code for reference

Answer (score 0):

Instead on using `Thread`, `Handler`, and `Thread.sleep`, Try to use only Handler. And try to use `postDelayed` in Handler. and you can remove the Handler runnable using `removeCallbacks`

Here is just gave example to change the onProgressChange method using Handler instead of Thread.

```
Runnable MyRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (highlightButtonWorkComplete && finalI == secondYellowColoredTextViewPosition) {


        } else {

            lnLinearlayout.getChildAt(finalI).setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
        }

        if (finalI == (lnLinearlayout.getChildCount() - 1)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < lnLinearlayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (highlightButtonWorkComplete && finalI == secondYellowColoredTextViewPosition) {
                    // leave this textview , as it is yellow ... go to next textview

                    secondYellowColoredTextViewPosition = 0;
                    highlightButtonWorkComplete = false;

                } else {

                    lnLinearlayout.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.color.grayColor);
                }
            }
            Log.d("Progress Status", "ProgressStatus" + progressStatus);

            if (progressStatus % 79 == 0) {
                lnLinearlayout.removeAllViews();
                generateView();
            }
        }

        if(progressStatus < 80) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }
};

private int progressStatus = 0;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    generateView();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    mHandler.removeCallbacks(MyRunnable);
}

private void generateView() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
        ln_highlightprogress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        LinearLayout mview = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        mview.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grayColor);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                7, 40);
        layoutParams.setMargins(2, 0, 2, 0);
        mview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        lnLinearlayout.addView(mview);
        Log.d("==================", "=================" + i);
        Log.v("==================", "=================" + i);
    }
    progressStatus = 0;
    mHandler.postDelayed(MyRunnable, 1000);
    // changeProgress();
}
```

Comment: That does mater I called **generateView();** in onResume you can call in your button click. I just gave a sample

Comment: Ok wait let me try  if any issue will come i will come i ll let u know

Comment: https://paste.ofcode.org/QCZYeUvJackUSrDZzCHKZZ  i am using this code after change but i am not able to change the color of other view only first item color changing @Muthukrishnan Rajendran

Comment: 1. Try to put **Runnable MyRunnable = new Runnable()** outside method, so that you can able to stop this runnable when onPause using removCallback, 2. Sorry, I don't have any idea what logic you defined to show color. For me, it should work fine what ever you put inside Runnable, Try to change your condition statement and check.